# Finding polar coordinates angle for complex numbers given cartesian form

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers, polar-coordinates, parametric

I have the following formula for finding $\theta$ given cartesian form of complex numbers.

$$\theta = \begin{cases} 
      \tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x}) & x \leq 0 \\
      \tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x}) & x \geq 0 \\
      \pm\frac{\pi}{2} & x = 0
   \end{cases}
$$

My confusion is when $x=0$. How do I tell if my angle is $\frac{\pi}{2}$ or $-\frac{\pi}{2}$

For example, let's say my complex number is $z = -i$

In that case $x=0$, so is the angle $\frac{\pi}{2}$ or $-\frac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation

Comment: Are you sure the first two cases are identical? You might have a typo. Otherwise it would just be $x\ne 0$

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2  ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to try to understand the reason why that formula is given in the first place. The angle $\theta$ is the angle the complex number in the plane makes with the positive real axis (positive $x$-axis). Counting the angle in the positive direction is done counter clockwise. So if $z = i$, then it is clearly $\displaystyle \frac{\pi}{2}$ away from the positive $x$-axis purely from looking at the diagram.

In sum, if $x = 0$ then we have that $z = iy$ for some real number $y$. If $y > 0$ then $\displaystyle \theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$ and if $y < 0$ we have $\displaystyle \theta = -\frac{\pi}{2}$, try to convince yourself of this!